# Unable to do GM_xmlhttprequest. The get request is not getting generated

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I have witten a scipt that collect the data from DOM and on a button click should send the data to a php script. The GM_xmlhttprequest methord is not generating any get request on checking in firebug.

One more thing can we use jQuery.ajax with in greasemonkey? (unable to get it work)

Below is the code:

```
                    // ==UserScript==
                    // @name        anna
                    // @namespace   *
                    // @description Script to send the data to a server during case closure
                    // @include     https://172.22.32.100/yii_entry.php?r=loader/load/url/case_detail.php3?ticket_num*
                    // @include     https://172.16.192.101/yii_entry.php?r=loader/load/url/case_detail.php3?ticket_num*
                    // @include     https://210.55.196.52/yii_entry.php?r=loader/load/url/case_detail.php3?ticket_num*
                    // @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
                    // @version     1
                    // @grant     none
                    //allowpaste
                    // ==/UserScript==

                    var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
                    $(document).ready(function()
                    {

                        console.log("jQuery is working");

                    });

                    $(window).load(function()
                    {
                      //console.log("1");
                      var x = $("#iframe").contents().find('#ticket_detail')[0].getElementsBySelector('.TableFormInput').last();
                      console.log('Anna ON!!!');
                      //console.log(btn);
                      var input=document.createElement("input");

                      input.type="button";
                      input.value="Send Data";
                      input.onclick = sendData;
                      input.class="btn";
                      //console.log("2");
                      x.appendChild(input); 
                       console.log("Button Created");

                      //Change itil value for Maps without ITIL:Damovo Pilot
                       var hostname = window.location.hostname;
                       if(hostname == "10.136.40.62")
                           {
                            var itil = "None";
                           }
                       else
                        {
                          var itil = $("#iframe").contents().find('#ticket_detail')[0].getElementsBySelector('#itil_category')[0].value; 
                        }

                       // Declare variables
                       var casenumber = $('h1[id=page-title]')[0].firstChild.data.split('-')[1].trim();
                       var casename = $("#iframe").contents().find('#ticket_detail')[0].getElementsBySelector('.TableFormInput')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data.trim();
                       var sev = $("#iframe").contents().find('#ticket_detail')[0].getElementsBySelector('#case_severity_id')[0].value;
                       var assigned = $("#iframe").contents().find('#ticket_detail')[0].getElementsBySelector('#assigned')[0].innerHTML.split('selected')[1].split('>')[1].split('<')[0];
                       var status = $("#iframe").contents().find('#ticket_detail')[0].getElementsBySelector('#status')[0].value;
                       //var data = $("#iframe").contents().find('.CaseSentryTicketHistoryItem')[0].innerHTML.split('Workflow')[1];
                       var lastUpdate = $('#util-nav').children()[0].href.split("id/")[1];

                      //Search the DOM for hash tag
                       var length = $("#iframe").contents().find('.CaseSentryTicketHistoryItem').length;
                       var x;
                       for(x = 0; x < length;)
                         {

                            var hash = $("#iframe").contents().find('.CaseSentryTicketHistoryItem')[x].innerHTML;
                            var num = hash.search("##RS##");
                            if(num !== -1)
                            {
                                var data = $("#iframe").contents().find('.CaseSentryTicketHistoryItem')[x].innerHTML.split('Workflow')[1];
                          //console.log(data);
                                break;  
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var data = "Pls use correct hash Tags";
                            }
                         x++;
                         }


                      var fin = "lastUpdated = "+lastUpdate+"\ncasenumber = "+casenumber+"\ncasename = "+casename+"\nsev = "+sev+"\nassigned = "+assigned+"\nitil = "+itil+"\nstatus = "+status+"\ndata = "+data;
                      //var fin = "lastUpdated = "+lastUpdate+"\ncasenumber = "+casenumber+"\ncasename = "+casename+"\nsev = \nassigned = "+assigned+"\nitil = "+itil+"\nstatus = "+status+"\ndata = ";
                      //var fin="lastUpdated="+lastUpdate+"&casenumber="+casenumber+"&casename="+casename+"&sev="+sev+"&assigned="+assigned+"&itil="+itil+"&status="+status+"&data="+data;
                      var send = "lastUpdated="+lastUpdate+"&casenumber="+casenumber+"&casename="+casename+"&sev="+sev+"&assigned="+assigned+"&itil="+itil+"&status="+status+"&data="+data;
                        var file = "http://66.187.221.213/mttr.php";
                      function sendData()
                      {
                        var r = confirm(fin);
                        if (r == true)
                        {
                         console.log("true");

                    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                      method: "GET",
                      url: "http://66.187.221.213/mttr.php/",
                      onload: function(response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                      }
                    });


                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            //do nothing
                        }

                      }


                    });
```

Comment: Your `@grant none` implies that there is no `GM_xmlhttpRequest` at all. `unsafeWindow` also. Due to some sandbox issues, please use the jQuery you `@require`d instead of the one from `unsafeWindow`.

Comment: if I use the @grant  then I get the error Error: Permission denied to access property 'apply'. is there any way around it?
If I dont use unsafeWindow i dont get $.(window) option. I need it as the page has images that i need it to load before kicking the script.

Comment: If i add the @grant  GM_xmlhttpRequest and remove the unsafeWindow then the script runs without creating the button. Pls help

Comment: Try removing var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;, and in the meta data add 
// @run-at        document-start